# If a weapon attack moves the creature within 5ft of a second creature, such as with Crusher, can Horde Breaker be used to attack the second creature?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, archetype

Horde Breaker states: "Once on each of your turns when you make a weapon attack, you can make another attack with the same weapon against a different creature that is within 5 feet of the original target and within range of your weapon."

The second portion of Crusher states: "Once per turn, when you hit a creature with an attack that deals bludgeoning damage, you can move it 5 feet to an unoccupied space, provided the target is no more than one size larger than you."

If I hit a creature with a bludgeoning attack, then use the Crusher feat to move that creature within 5th of a second creature, can Horde Breaker grant me an attack against the second creature?

Answer (score 11):

### Timing issues

The timing of the two is fixed and makes it - as depicted - incompatible.

- Horde Breaker triggers on *when you make a weapon attack*, which is the moment the target is determined and the dice are rolled.
- Crusher triggers on *when you hit*, which happens the moment the dice come to a stop and the result is calculated to be a hit, which chronologically is after the attack is rolled.

As such, the outcome of Crusher can no longer trigger Horde Breaker: the declaration of Horde Breaker needs to happen when it triggers, so *before* the dice get dropped into motion.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning it is possible to set up Horde Breaker this way with your second attack granted by Extra Attack as a ranger. You don't even need to hit with the second attack in order to make the Horde Breaker attack provided you hit the first time to proc crusher.

Comment: @KakunaRattata that's not the situation asked by OP.

Comment: True, but I still think it's a relevant consideration if the OP is looking for ways to use Crusher to interact with Hordebreaker. Since it's a 3rd level ranger feature and the player bothered to pick up a feat based on attacking, I would assume they would probably be getting extra attack eventually, even possibly dual wielding.

Answer (score 1):

### Yes

I see this a bit differently than Trish does in their [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/205977/44231). I would say that with horde breaker you do the normal attack and when that is finished you may or may not be able to make an extra attack. The wording is "when you make an attack" and it's reasonable to say that that is when you decide to attack. But it continues with "... you can make another attack ..." and you obviously won't take this second attack right then and there before the first one is done. When you're done resolving the first attack, *Crusher* rider included, the second target is eligible for the *Horde Breaker* attack.

Comment: I think given the ambiguity here, a strong argument can be made for following the Rule of Cool.

Comment: I did consider changing my "Yes" to "It's up to the DM", which is a valid answer to any question regarding 5e. =P